# Catch all Pending or Rejected actions within a redux-toolkit slice

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-observable, redux-toolkit

Aight.. so im pretty new with redux toolkit and I want to catch ALL pending actions in one slice to basically show a loading modal. I know we can do this with `redux-saga` and probably `redux-observable`

Soooooo instead of

```
 builder.addCase(fetchUsers.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = LoadingState.PENDING;
 });
```

To Something like this

```
 builder.addCase(allActions.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = LoadingState.PENDING;
 });
```

I know `allActions` does not work there but is there anything that will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the matching utilities included in RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities):

```js
import { createSlice, isPending} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  reducers: { /* */ },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addMatcher(isPending, (state, action) => {
      // logic here
    })

  }
})
```

You can also combine the matching utilities in various ways to only handle the pending state for specific thunks, etc.

Comment: How to filter actions by the current slice without name copypaste?